# Populating Google Form text box from Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I am currently creating a form in Google Forms. It is already connected to sheets to populate a sheet. In the sheets app, I created a new sheet within the workbook that finds the last submission, and uses vlookup to get a few columns for that last submission.

What I want: Next time I submit a form, I want to have some text before, say, Question 1 which says "On your last submission, you said $X$." I want to fill in the X. Note: I do not want to populate the answer box, or the multiple choice options with data from the sheet. There are quite a few articles online describing how to do this with AppsScript. All I want is to pull data from, say, 'Sheet2!A2' and have it display in the *description* section of a question or text block in the form. (the form data itself is published to Sheet1, not Sheet2... Sheet2 is created to easily find the one cell I actually want)

Any ideas?

**MWE**: [Form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1RErflsBdkXTyszk4OBQ7X5KR4SK7swaHPUbzmKPJgRA/edit) | [Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i1BdcTgt6axRUIMOE9rWLoP2yeIZcVWaDFVM6YmPZF0/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Have you investigated the Apps Script method [setHelpText](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item#sethelptexttext)?  This is what sets the description section of the question.

Comment: Hi there @ AaronWolf! In addition to what @AaronDuniganAtLee commented, could you please share publicly the Form/Apps Script project of your scenario? They aren't accessible.

Comment: The Form has been updated to be accessible.